# How can I send additional web page metadata to my Cordova app other than URL?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently using [this](https://github.com/wjbergin/virtualartifacts-webintent.git) Cordova plugin to share a webpage url from a web browser to my Cordova Android app, which works as expected.

I'd like to know if it's possible to amend the [WebIntent.java](https://github.com/wjbergin/virtualartifacts-webintent/blob/master/src/android/WebIntent.java) file to retrieve more metadata from the webpage (such as description/tags meta content, og tags, etc), add it to the intent and send it to my app. Failing that, how might one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to leave the plugin as is and fetch the shared url's page metadata separately using this approach:

1. Load the shared url in a hidden [`InAppBrowser`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) window.
2. When the page has finished loading and the `loadstop` event is fired, call `inAppBrowser.executeScript` function to run code that will return the loaded page's DOM as a string.
3. Using the returned DOM, load it into a new [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then query it to pick out the desired metadata tags.